# Remove 'username' field from django-allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth

When django-registration doesn't support django 1.5 and custom user model. I'm trying use django-allauth, from first look it's great product.

Problem i have - username field required, but in my app i don't have username's. So, allauth documentation says:

```
**Available settings:**
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD (="username" | "email" | "username_email")
```

Specifies the login method to use -- whether the user logs in by entering his username, e-mail address, or either one of both.

**Ok, i done, and got error:**

```
AssertionError at /accounts/signup/
No exception supplied
```

**models.py:**

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    title = models.CharField ('Name', max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField('Email', max_length=255, unique=True)
    ...
```

**settings.py**

```
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = ('email')
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'internboard.MyUser'
```

What i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Thanks, i found, right settings for my task:

```
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
```

Comment: Hi Rukomoynikov, did you have to make your own user model for this to work?  If so, what did it look like exactly (if you are willing to share) ?

Comment: More recent resource from official doc. http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#custom-user-models

Comment: The only problem with this is that if the user signs up with say facebook they don't have a user name in the Django user account.

Answer (score 48):

If you encounter the error `django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: Account has no field named 'username'` with reference to `USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD` in the stacktrace, you'll also need to set `ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD` to `None` (or the appropriate field for your use case). The full set of settings needed are the following:

```py
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
```

This setting is explained in more detail in the django-allauth documentation for [Custom User Models](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#custom-user-models) with defaults outlined in [Configuration](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html).

Comment: thanks a lot, this fix the FieldDoesNotExist error

Answer (score 2):

A probable cause could be any of the following for a custom user model;

a) if you've totally eliminated "Username" as a field in your model, then, do ensure that in your model, you define the variable:

```
               USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

Also, do ensure that in the field definition of email, the field attribute;

```
              unique = True
```

is as well included.

b) In your custom User admin (which must be compulsorily configured), the form and add_form variables must be defined to inherit from "ModelForm" or UserCreationForm (for the add_form variable).

c) if you're inheriting allauth's Signup Form, then, you'll have to declare in your settings:

```
 ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FILED = None
```

Most importantly, ensure you write tests to ensure that form posts data and saves to the database. Thanks. Hope someone finds this helpful..... Remember, it can only be hard, but never impossible!!!  Happy 'Djangoing'....