# Accept username OR email for logging in with django-allauth

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-allauth

I see django-allauth supports forcing users to login using their email address, and doesn't ask them for a username when signing up (instead generating one automatically from the email address) - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19683532/221001

Is it possible to have a user sign up, entering an email address and username manually, and then allow them to sign in using either? (e.g. there are two fields on the Login page: "username or email" and "password")

Comment: ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD=“username_email”
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
in your setting.py file

Comment: for more info visit http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Yogesh posted above, the `username_email` value for `ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD` does the job.

http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html

Comment: Why has this answer been downvoted? This is the correct answer and provides a link to the docs. Thanks :)