# Django registration that works well with django-authtools

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-registration

I have a Django app that uses django-authtools which provides a custom auth model so that I can use email as user id.

I am wondering if there is a reusable app that I can reuse for doing registrations. Something like django-registration-redux but that works well with the just using email as user id. Or can django-registration-redux be used in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I figured that what I was trying to achieve is achieved by using django-allauth instead. This link shows the way how to achieve it:

I think I can achieve what I am trying to do how it is specified in [Remove 'username' field from django-allauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19683179/remove-username-field-from-django-allauth). So I guess