# django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: User has no field named 'username'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to customize django's AbstractUser. When I try to reset `username` to `None`, I get the following exception:

```
"django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: User has no field named 'username'".
```

Here is my code:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("L'adresse e-mail donnée doit etre definie")
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", False)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", True)

        if extra_fields.get("is_staff") is not True:
            raise ValueError("Superuser must have is_staff=True")
        if extra_fields.get("is_superuser") is not True:
            raise ValueError("Superuser must have is_superuser=True")
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField('email adress', unique=True)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Please add the _full_ error traceback to your question. Also have you set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your settings?

Comment: I doubt you can "remove" the username field like that. It is a field coming from the `AbstractUser`. If you don't want to use it, maybe redefine it with a default and readonly? Or what exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't set a value for `USERNAME_FIELD` in your code. This must be set to a field that uniquely identifies a user instance. `AbstractUser` sets this to `'username'` and hence you are getting the error. You can set this to `'email'` to solve your problem:

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField('email adress', unique=True)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    # set below value
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

Answer (score 13):

This might have also caused if you are using django-allauth in your project.To fix this you need to define ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD to None inside settings.py. Refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19683179/remove-username-field-from-django-allauth) and [allauth documentation](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html) for more information.

```
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
```

Comment: If it gives `AssertionError` then use your username field instead of `None` eg. `ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'`

Comment: Why are you assuming we're using allauth?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html), you have to add in the settings file:

```
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD ="email"
```

But first you have to add to your model the following:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField('email adress', unique=True)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
```

Comment: link  to docs is dead

Comment: you could refer https://docs.allauth.org/en/latest/account/advanced.html#custom-user-models , for settings required while using a custom model in django allauth. For details regarding each config you could use : https://docs.allauth.org/en/latest/account/configuration.html

Comment: Why are you assuming we're using allauth?

Answer (score 0):

What's the reason to set username as None?

User model must has a unique field like a username or email or phone_number to identificate user.

If you want to override user's model, you should to provide such unique field, mark it as username field and set django settings variable AUTH_USER_MODEL defining your customized model.

Something like this:

```py
# model
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)  # or something else
    ...

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'


# settings
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
```